# how to iterate using .each and scrape data in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, nokogiri, scrape

I am pretty new to programming and need some help/feedback on my code. My goal is to scrape the location, its details and then display that data to my user in a numbered list. I am simply having difficulty displaying this data. I'm having trouble with the iteration using the .each method. I tried to do the iteration with the travel_details but its not working. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help/feedback!

The output I want will look like this:

```
Which location you would like to know more about?
 1. Nairobi, Kenya
2. Juneau, United States
3. Hong Kong
4. Litchfield National Park, Australia
5. Patagonia, Chile
6. Yukon, Canada
7. San Juan, Puerto Rico
8. Panama
9. Matera, Italy
10. Yokohama, Japan
```

---- UPDATE ---

I was able to update my code. Below is the input. I would like help on the show_selection and get selection methods now. Once the user enters a number for the place they want to see, the code should look at the Travel_Cli::Place.all class array and put the appropriate name and summary. It should then display it in the show_selection method. I think that I should use the .find index to see if it equals the input but not sure how. In the coding, I placed my desired output.
This will allow the user to decide which location they would like to learn more about.

```
# CLI Controller
class TravelCli::Cli

  attr_accessor :locale

def call
  welcome
  list_places
  input = nil
  while input != "exit"
    input = gets.chomp.downcase
  if input == "list"
      list_places
  elsif !(0..10).include?(input.to_i)
      puts "You have not selected a valid option."
  elsif input != "exit"
      @locale = input
      show_selection
    end
    menu
  end
  #goodbye
end


def get_selection
   #Place instance that you will get from Place.all
    #TravelCli::Place.all.each {|place| puts "#{place.summary}"}
    #TravelCli::Place.all.find_index { |p| place.summary == locale } #have to define input
    #TravelCli::Place.find_index {|place| place == @locale }
    TravelCli::Place.all.each_with_index do |place, i|
    if locale == place.name[i+1]
        return true
    end
   #binding.pry
end

def show_selection
  get_selection
  puts "Here is more information about  #{locale}."
  puts
  puts " display details from get_selection"


  #outputs the summary of the input from the place.all array
end

def menu
puts "Type 'exit' to quit"
puts "Type 'list' to list places"
end


def welcome
  puts " Feel Like Traveling? "
  puts "     "
  puts "----10 Of The Best Travel Destinations You Should Visit In 2019-----"
  puts "     "
end

def get_places
  TravelCli::Scrape.scrape_places
end

def list_places
  get_places
  TravelCli::Place.all.each.with_index(1) {|place, i| puts "#{i}. #{place.name}"}
  puts
  puts " Which Location would you like to learn more about?:   "
end


 def goodbye
   puts "Happy Travels!"
 end

end
```

```
class TravelCli::Scrape

  URL = 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/louisekhong/bring-me-2019-best-travel-destinations'

    def self.scrape_places
        Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).css('.subbuzz').each do |place|
          TravelCli::Place.new(
            place.css('.js-subbuzz__title-text').text.strip,
            place.css('.subbuzz__description').text.strip)
        end
    end
  end
```

```
class TravelCli::Place
  attr_accessor :name, :summary, :place

  @@all = []


def initialize(name, summary)
    @name = name
    @summary = summary
    @@all << self
 end

 def self.all
   @@all
 end



end
```

Comment: "I am simply having difficulty" / "I'm having trouble" / "its not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Codestyle [doesn't recommend](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars) to use class variables.

Comment: I've added an answer which gives you the output you want based on the previous answer, which gives you the setup you need.

Comment: see my updated answer,  it is a full working program doing what you want

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. You want to figure out what the container for each individual location is, and loop over that. In this case, it's `.subbuzz`. Each `.subbuzz` has a `.js-subbuzz__title-text` (the location name) and `.subbuzz__description` (the description text). Also, I used a single array of objects to represent each location, instead of trying to maintain multiple arrays and keep the values in sync.

You did have an important typo in your code as well. You initialized `@travel_details = []`, but filled it using `@@travel_details << ele....`. `@travel_details` is an instance variable. `@@travel_details` is a class variable. They're quite different. I imagine you received `Undefined method << for nil:NilClass` when you ran your code because of that.

If you have any questions about this, definitely feel free to ask!

**Code:**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

module TravelCli
  Place = Struct.new(:title, :description, :image_url) do
    def to_s
      <<~TEXT
        Title: #{title}
        Description: #{description}
      TEXT
    end
  end

  class Places
    URL = 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/louisekhong/bring-me-2019-best-travel-destinations'

    def self.print
      places = new
      places.scrape

      puts places.list.map(&:to_s).join("\n")
    end

    attr_reader :list

    def scrape
      @list = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).css('.subbuzz').map do |place|
        Place.new(
          place.css('.js-subbuzz__title-text').text.strip,
          place.css('.subbuzz__description').text.strip,
        )
      end
    end

  end
end

TravelCli::Places.print
```

**Output:**

```
Title: Nairobi, Kenya
Description: Who'll love it: animal loversWhy go in 2019: Thanks to the recent launch of a direct flight route between Nairobi and New York City, spotting elusive lions and leopards on safari is now just that liiiiitttle bit easier. As both Africa's safari capital and one of the continent's fastest growing cities, Nairobi offers a unique contrast between the city and the wild.

Title: Juneau, United States
Description: Who’ll love it: foodiesWhy go in 2019: Juneau, Alaska, is having a foodie moment (I mean, why else would it be hosting the 2019 International Food Blogger Conference?). Focusing on fresh, local seafood and wild fruits, the food scene here is understated, delicious, and eco-friendly by nature. Be sure to check out Salt, an up-and-coming modern Alaskan restaurant that serves food foraged by the chef himself.

Title: Hong Kong
Description: Who’ll love it: solo travelers Why go in 2019: Hong Kong may be a small island, but it's bursting with culture! New and exciting attractions, including museums and a huge cultural center, make it the perfect city to explore solo. M+ Museum is slated to open this year and at 17,000 square meters, it'll be one of the largest museums of modern visual culture in the world. It's also one of the world's safest cities, which is comforting to know if you’re traveling on your own.

Title: Litchfield National Park, Australia
Description: Who'll love it: escapistsWhy go in 2019: With hiking trails through striking landscapes, epic 4WD tracks, and stunning waterfalls that lead to glistening natural pools, a visit to Litchfield National Park will make you forget that the rest of the world exists. Located ~90 minutes south of Darwin, it's smaller than the popular Kakadu National Park (and has fewer tourists!), and it's currently undergoing improvements that'll see new campgrounds and swimming spots open this year.

Title: Patagonia, Chile
Description: Who’ll love it: adventure seekersWhy go in 2019: Any serious adventurer will love the new massive hiking trail that connects 17 different national parks. Created as part of a huge conservation effort, the Route of Parks in Patagonian spans 1,740 miles and takes travelers on a scenic journey through parks like Torres del Paine and San Rafael Lagoon. It's the perfect way to experience some of Chile's incredible natural beauty.

Title: Yukon, Canada
Description: Who'll love it: nature loversWhy go in 2019: The Yukon territory is a prime place to catch a glimpse of the northern lights, and soon you'll be able to see them in a whole new way — on board a private jet! The Aurora 360 is taking flight for the first time in February, but if you don't make it in time for that, camping out in a tent is equally as magical. While you're there, make sure you visit Kluane National Park and Reserve to hike up Mount Logan, Canada's tallest peak.

Title: San Juan, Puerto Rico
Description: Who'll love it: conscientious travelers Why go in 2019: Since the devastation of Hurricane Maria in 2017, Puerto Rico has made huge strides in rebuilding the island and tourism is a key way to keep that regrowth underway. With amazing food (visit the famous Pork Highway just outside of San Juan), colorful architecture, and gorgeous natural beauty, traveling to the island this year doesn’t just benefit Puerto Ricans, but will also be a trip of a lifetime.

Title: Panama
Description: Who'll love it: party goers and beach bumsWhy go in 2019: This year marks the 500 year anniversary of Panama City and a celebration you won't want to miss. Special events such as parades, exhibitions, and musical shows are running until mid-August, but you can party with the locals and explore the historic old town year-round. When you're ready for some R&R, head up north to the blindingly white sand and clear waters of Bocas Del Toro.

Title: Matera, Italy
Description: Who’ll love it: history buffsWhy go in 2019: As one of the world’s oldest continuously inhabited cities, Matera has been named one of 2019’s European Capitals of Culture for its cultural importance (and stunning beauty). Its blend of ancient architecture and modern dining and entertainment is absolutely enchanting. Any place where you can spend days learning about 12th-century churches and nights dining on Italian food in an underground grotto restaurant is a winner for us.

Title: Yokohama, Japan
Description: Who'll love it: sports fansWhy go in 2019: Sporting fever is taking over Japan as it gears up for the 2019 Rugby World Cup in September (and let's not forget the Olympics in 2020). Just over 30 minutes south of Tokyo, the colorful harbor city of Yokohama is home to Japan's largest stadium and will play host to seven games — including the final. The food is also incredible: we recommend visiting the Shin-Yokohama Ramen Museum and snacking your way through Chinatown (it's the biggest in Japan!).
```

Comment: I was getting a new MethodError. In your output, you created an object Place which has a title and description.   I wanted it to produce an output of "  1. Nairobi, Kenya
 2. Juneau, United States  3. Hong Kong 4. Litchfield National Park, Australia  5. Patagonia, Chile   6. Yukon, Canada  7. San Juan, Puerto Rico  8. Panama
  9. Matera, Italy 10. Yokohama, Japan". Where the user can select which location they want to see the description of. Instead of having Place (title, description), I am trying to have separate arrays.

Comment: @TyKendall can you give an example of desired output?

Comment: Just updated my question with the desired output, sorry.

Comment: @TyKendall `@list` is an array of objects which you should be able to do whatever you want with.  See https://pastebin.com/vRABQn7L for what `@lists` is.  You just need to write the methods you want to do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: @TyKendall the print and to_s methods were just to show you how to use this. You didn’t put all of you CLI code in your question originally, and I thought your whole problem was that you were having troubles scraping the website, and I got that to work for you. I’ll update my answer shortly with your new rest of the CLI class and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your program based on the previous answer including the fix to smashed together sentences bug in **scraper** , just remove `strip`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'

module TravelCli
  Place = Struct.new(:title, :description, :image_url) do
    def to_s
      <<~TEXT
        Title: #{title}
        Description: #{description}
      TEXT
    end
  end

  class Places
    URL = 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/louisekhong/bring-me-2019-best-travel-destinations'

    def self.run
      places = new
      places.scrape
      list = places.list
      output = lambda do
        list.each_with_index{|l, i| puts "#{i+1}. #{l.title}"}
        puts "\nSelect a place by number or type exit: "
      end
      input = ''
      loop do
        output.call
        input = gets.chomp
        break if input == "exit"
        item = list[input.to_i-1]
        puts "\n"
        puts item[:title]
        puts item[:description]
        puts "\n"
      end
    end

    attr_reader :list

    def scrape
      @list = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).css('.subbuzz').map do |place|
        Place.new(
          place.css('.js-subbuzz__title-text').text,
          place.css('.subbuzz__description').text,
        )
      end
    end
  end
end

TravelCli::Places.run
```

Run program and you will get this output:

```
1. Nairobi, Kenya
2. Juneau, United States
3. Hong Kong
4. Litchfield National Park, Australia
5. Patagonia, Chile
6. Yukon, Canada
7. San Juan, Puerto Rico
8. Panama
9. Matera, Italy
10. Yokohama, Japan

Select a place by number or type exit:
```

Comment: In the run class method, you're taking the new places object, then you are scraping the website. What does list = places.list do?

Comment: I was able to update my code. Below is the input. I would like help on the show_selection and get selection methods now. Once the user enters a number for the place they want to see, the code should look look at the Travel_Cli::Place.all class array and put the appropriate name and summary. It should then display it in the show_selection method. I think that I should use the .find index to see if it equals the input but not sure how. In the coding, I placed my desired output.